# How to trigger a watch when i click my button several times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can i do a $watch() on a button and trigger my $watch() when i press this button several times...?

***html:***

```
<button ng-click="addWatch()" style="margin-left:10px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
                    Re-init tableau
</button>


....

<mtx-matrice-form matrix="matrix " isclicked="isWatchAdded "></mtx-matrice-form>
```

***js controller:***

```
$scope.addWatch = function(){
    if( !$scope.isWatchAdded ) {
      $scope.isWatchAdded = true;
    }
}
```

***directive:***

```
angular.module('matrixarMatrice', []).directive('mtxMatriceForm', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'views/matrice/matrice.html',
        scope: {
            matrix: '=',
            isWatchAdded : '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
...
          $scope.$watch('isWatchAdded ', function () {}, true);    

...
```

it's run on time i want to run when i click my button

Comment: the $watch() is triggered every time there is a change detected on `$scope.isWatchAdded` but you seem to be only changing `$scope.isWatchAdded` once, i.e. setting it to `true`. You're gonna have to toggle `$scope.isWatchAdded` on every click of the button to trigger a `$watch()`

Comment: @dcodesmith how i can toggle this on every click .?

Comment: `$scope.isWatchAdded = !$scope.isWatchAdded`

Comment: @dcodesmith ok thx for yu're help